# Attack on Titan Opening Themes

Tags: attack-on-titan, theme-song

I'm having trouble matching the 3 opening themes to Attack on Titan to tracks available to purchase in various digital outlets.

For the avoidance of confusion, I'm looking for the long versions of the three tracks featured on this YouTube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKbbMsvyOpo

Thanks to other questions and answers on the site I'm confident that the first one is Guren no Yumiya by Linked Horizon, but while I think the 3rd one should be called Shingeki no Kyojin, I'm struggling to match it to an artist and I'm exactly nowhere with the 2nd one.

Comment: As mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_on_Titan#Music), they're the 1st (Guren no Yumiya) and 2nd (Jiyuu no Tsubasa) opening of season 1, and the 1st (Shinzou wo Sasageyo!) opening of season 2, all by Linked Horizon.

Comment: If you write that up as an answer I can mark it right. Feeling pretty sheepish for not moving on from Google searches to the obvious Wikipedia page. 

Comment: if the answer is given in commentary you can self-answer your question by quoting the comment or you can close it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attack_on_Titan#Music), they're the 1st (Guren no Yumiya) and 2nd (Jiyuu no Tsubasa) opening of season 1, and the 1st (Shinzou wo Sasageyo!) opening of season 2, all by Linked Horizon.

Thanks to Aki Tanaka